# Runtime calculation according to all actions

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I have a question please, I have the following code and I need to calculate its running time. I made a calculation by all the operations of the code and the result that came out to me is O(n^2) but I'm not sure I would be happy to help.

```
S1=O(1), S2=O(1)
for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
  for (j = 1; j <= i; j++)
    for (k = 1; k <= 10; k++)
    S1;
    S2;
}
```

Is this equation correct?

[image: The runtime equation]

thank's

Answer (score 0):

Your final result is correct.
This is how I'd estimate the computational complexity `N`:

```
N = 10 + 20 + 30 + 40 +  .... + 10*n
N = 10 * [1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + ... + n ]
N = 10 * n*n
N = O(n*n)
```